# Laravel cannot protect API routes

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, routes

I have the following route in my `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('users/', 'Api\UserController@index');
});
```

This constantly redirects me to my dashboard.

Then I try this:

```
 Route::get('users/', 'Api\UserController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

This works but it doesn't not protect the route, so I can still access it if I am logged out.

Any Ideas why this is? I'm not sure what the best way is to authenticate API routes, what it the usual convention?

I am using Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `auth` middleware in `api.php` routes, only in `web.php`. But you may use the `auth:api` middleware.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#protecting-routes

Comment: I see, couldn't see that anywhere in the docs. So does that mean I have to use Passport with this?

Comment: I have tried to use `auth:api` like this: `Route::get('/users', 'Api\UserController@index')->middleware('auth:api');`but it redirects me to my dashboard. Is there anything I need to change in the AuthServiceProvider or any other config?

Comment: You don't need to use passport specifically, there are a number of other api auth packages out there. This one is quite commonly used: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth